# Read list of file names from web into R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to read a lot of csv files into R from a website.  Threa are multiple years of daily (business days only) files.  All of the files have the same data structure.  I can sucessfully read *one* file using the following logic:

```
# enter user credentials
user     <- "JohnDoe"
password <- "SecretPassword"
credentials <- paste(user,":",password,"@",sep="")
web.site <- "downloads.theice.com/Settlement_Reports_CSV/Power/"

# construct path to data
path <- paste("https://", credentials, web.site, sep="")

# read data for 4/10/2013
file  <- "icecleared_power_2013_04_10"
fname <- paste(path,file,".dat",sep="")
df <- read.csv(fname,header=TRUE, sep="|",as.is=TRUE)
```

However, Im looking for tips on how to read all the files in the directory at once.  I suppose I could generate a sequence of dates an construct the file name above in a loop and use rbind to append each file but that seems cumbersome.  Plus there will be issues when attempting to read weekends and holidays where there is no files.

The impages below show what the list of files look like in the web browser:

[image: file list in browser part 1]

...
...
...

[image: file list in browser part 2]

Is there a way to scan the path (from above) to get a list of all the file names in the directory first that meet a certin crieteia (i.e. start with "icecleared_power_" as there are also some files in that location that have a different starting name that I do not want to read in) then loop the read.csv through that list and use rbind to append?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: What does the actual webpage look like in a browser? Is there an index page of some sort that you can easily screen/web-scrape to get the list relevant files to construct your download commands?

Comment: Ananda:  please see edits with web browser screen shots.

Answer (score 6):

I would first try to just scrape the links to the relevant data files and use the resulting information to construct the full download path that includes user logins and so on. As others have suggested, `lapply` would be convenient for batch downloading.

Here's an easy way to extract the URLs. Obviously, modify the example to suit your actual scenario.

Here, we're going to use the `XML` package to identify all the links available at the CRAN archives for the Amelia package (http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Amelia/).

```
> library(XML)
> url <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Amelia/"
> doc <- htmlParse(url)
> links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")
> free(doc)
> links
                   href                    href                    href 
             "?C=N;O=D"              "?C=M;O=A"              "?C=S;O=A" 
                   href                    href                    href 
             "?C=D;O=A" "/src/contrib/Archive/"  "Amelia_1.1-23.tar.gz" 
                   href                    href                    href 
 "Amelia_1.1-29.tar.gz"  "Amelia_1.1-30.tar.gz"  "Amelia_1.1-32.tar.gz" 
                   href                    href                    href 
 "Amelia_1.1-33.tar.gz"   "Amelia_1.2-0.tar.gz"   "Amelia_1.2-1.tar.gz" 
                   href                    href                    href 
  "Amelia_1.2-2.tar.gz"   "Amelia_1.2-9.tar.gz"  "Amelia_1.2-12.tar.gz" 
                   href                    href                    href 
 "Amelia_1.2-13.tar.gz"  "Amelia_1.2-14.tar.gz"  "Amelia_1.2-15.tar.gz" 
                   href                    href                    href 
 "Amelia_1.2-16.tar.gz"  "Amelia_1.2-17.tar.gz"  "Amelia_1.2-18.tar.gz" 
                   href                    href                    href 
  "Amelia_1.5-4.tar.gz"   "Amelia_1.5-5.tar.gz"   "Amelia_1.6.1.tar.gz" 
                   href                    href                    href 
  "Amelia_1.6.3.tar.gz"   "Amelia_1.6.4.tar.gz"     "Amelia_1.7.tar.gz"
```

For the sake of demonstration, imagine that, ultimately, we only want the links for the 1.2 versions of the package.

```
> wanted <- links[grepl("Amelia_1\\.2.*", links)]
> wanted
                  href                   href                   href 
 "Amelia_1.2-0.tar.gz"  "Amelia_1.2-1.tar.gz"  "Amelia_1.2-2.tar.gz" 
                  href                   href                   href 
 "Amelia_1.2-9.tar.gz" "Amelia_1.2-12.tar.gz" "Amelia_1.2-13.tar.gz" 
                  href                   href                   href 
"Amelia_1.2-14.tar.gz" "Amelia_1.2-15.tar.gz" "Amelia_1.2-16.tar.gz" 
                  href                   href 
"Amelia_1.2-17.tar.gz" "Amelia_1.2-18.tar.gz"
```

You can now use that vector as follows:

```
wanted <- links[grepl("Amelia_1\\.2.*", links)]
GetMe <- paste(url, wanted, sep = "")
lapply(seq_along(GetMe), 
       function(x) download.file(GetMe[x], wanted[x], mode = "wb"))
```

---

#### Update (to clarify your question in comments)

The last step in the example above *downloads* the specified files to your current working directory (use `getwd()` to verify where that is). If, instead, you know for sure that `read.csv` works on the data, you can also try to modify your anonymous function to read the files directly:

```
lapply(seq_along(GetMe), 
       function(x) read.csv(GetMe[x], header = TRUE, sep = "|", as.is = TRUE))
```

However, I think a *safer* approach might be to download all the files into a single directory first, and then use `read.delim` or `read.csv` or whatever works to read in the data, similar to as was suggested by @Andreas. I say *safer* because it gives you more flexibility in case files aren't fully downloaded and so on. In that case, instead of having to redownload everything, you would only need to download the files which were not fully downloaded.

Comment: Thanks this looks like it will work great once I get the htmlParse to work.  For some reason, with my URL I get the following error: "Error: XML content does not seem to be XML, nor to identify a file name" any ideas?

Comment: I seemed to have moved past the "Error:XML..." issue by modifing the htmlParse as follows: doc <- htmlParse(readLines(url), asText=TRUE).  I understand the logic to get "wanted" and "GetMe".  However, what is happening in the lapply has got me a little confused, as I am not sure where the files being downloaded are stored or how to use the data contained within.

Comment: @MikeTP, the `lapply` step should be modified to suit your needs. In this example, since the files were binary, I just downloaded them to my working directory. If you know for sure that you can read them directly from the online source, then you can probably replace `download.file(...)` with your `read.csv(...)` command. This would read all of the files into a `list`, and from there, you can keep them as separate `data.frames` or, if the structure is all the same, you can `rbind` them into a single `data.frame`. Hope that helps!

Comment: THANKS! I had to use the library `httr` to gain access to the database first, e.g., `library(httr)`, then `GET(url, authenticate("email@email.com", "password"), write_disk("test.html"))`, then `doc <- htmlParse("test.html")`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the command "download.file".

```
### set up the path and destination
path <- "url where file is located"
dest <- "where on your hard disk you want the file saved"

### Ask R to try really hard to download your ".csv"
try(download.file(path, dest))
```

The trick to this is going to be figuring out how the "url" or "path" changes systematically between files. Often times, web pages are built such that the "url's" are systematic. In this case, you could potentially create a vector or data frame of url's to iterate over inside of an apply function.

All of this can be sandwiched inside of an "lapply". The "data" object is simply whatever we are iterating over. It could be a vector of URL's or a data frame of year and month observations, which could then be used to create URL's within the "lapply" function.

```
### "dl" will apply a function to every element in our vector "data"
  # It will also help keep track of files which have no download data
dl <- lapply(data, function(x) {
        path <- 'url'
        dest <- './data_intermediate/...'
        try(download.file(path, dest))
      })

### Assign element names to your list "dl"
names(dl) <- unique(data$name)
index     <- sapply(dl, is.null)

### Figure out which downloads returned nothing
no.download <- names(dl)[index]
```

You can then use "list.files()" to merge all data together, assuming they belong in one data.frame

```
### Create a list of files you want to merge together
files <- list.files()

### Create a list of data.frames by reading each file into memory
data  <- lapply(files, read.csv)

### Stack data together
data <- do.call(rbind, data)
```

Sometimes, you will notice the file has been corrupted after downloading. In this case, pay attention to the option contained within the download.file() command, "mode". You can set mode = "w" or mode = "wb" if the file is stored in a binary format.

Comment: thanks for your help.  where does "data" come from in the lapply function?

Comment: "data" is simply the object you are iterating over. For example, it could be a vector of URL's which point to the file you want to download. Or, it might be a data frame of year and month observations which help us create a URL within each loop.

Answer (score 1):

@MikeTP, if all the reports start with "icecleared_power_" and a date which is a business date the package "timeDate" offers an easy way to create a vector of business dates, like so:

```
require(timeDate)
tSeq <- timeSequence("2012-01-01","2012-12-31") # vector of days
tBiz <- tSeq[isBizday(tSeq)] # vector of business days
```

and

```
paste0("icecleared_power_",as.character.Date(tBiz))
```

gives you the concatenated file name.

If the web site follows a different logic regarding the naming of files we need more information as Ananda Mahto observed.

Keep in mind that when you create a date vector with timeDate you can get much more sophisticated then my simple example. You can take into account holiday schedules, stock exchange dates etc.

Comment: Thanks. I think it makes more sense for me to use the Ananda's sugesstion but I will take a look at timeDate as it looks usefull for other applications.  I really appreciate your response.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
for( i in seq_along(stations)) {
     URL<-""
      files<-rvest::read_html(URL) %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text(trim = T) 
      files<-grep(stations[i],files ,ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE )   
      destfile<- paste0("C:/Users/...",files)
      download.file(URL,destfile, mode="wb") 
   }
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining to the OP how to get the list of 'stations' and/or URL values, as that was part of the original question.