# download files from website when URL for parent directory gives 404

Tags: r, web-scraping

I don't already know what files exist, but I know the basic structure of the URL for a bunch of files that definitely do exist. I'd like to learn what they are and download them.

I can download an individual file without issue, in this case the land cover data for Alleghany county in Maryland:

```
download.file("https://cicwebresources.blob.core.windows.net/chesapeakebaylandcover/MD/ALLE_24001.zip"
    , destfile ="data/GIS_downloads/")
```

But I'd like to download all the land cover data .zip files for the state of MD.

I saw some [examples of webscraping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15956432/8400969) that went something like this, and trying to make it work for my situation:

```
library(stringi)
baseURL<- "https://cicwebresources.blob.core.windows.net/chesapeakebaylandcover/MD/"
doc <- read_html(baseURL)
# etc
```

but the URL for what I want to call the "parent directory" returns a 404 error.

How can I list all the .zip files for MD, given that I know they all share the same URL format but don't know the specific strings for each county etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the numbers might be FIPS codes. See if the structure `[FIRST 4 LETTERS]_24[FIPS code].zip` works and if so you could find a list of counties in MD and their FIPS codes (e.g., scrape [this wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_in_Maryland#List_of_counties), though I think the `tidycensus` package has this available as built-in data), and then build the URLs for each county.

Comment: Thanks, that might be the perfect workaround for this situation! Still eager to learn the more general case where I don't know what files are or aren't there, I just know there is at least 1 file, does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but I don't think there is a good general solution. Sounds like you don't have view permission for the parent directory, which means you can't know what files are in it.

Comment: I think combining *"I don't already know what files exist"* with the websites preference to not give you filenames (including your `".../MD/"` link returning "BlobNotFound") leads me to think that they don't want you to scrape their data like that (or that they haven't organized themselves to simplify this). I think Gregor's is better than nothing, but it might be useful to reach out to the data managers?

Comment: Thanks Gregor and r2evans!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 error should be taken at face value... maybe the solution is to go from a webpage that can load, and find the needed links there. As @Gregor Thomas and @r2evans suggested, the website wasn't letting me access the parent directory, so a workaround was called for.

In this case, I found the links listed on another webpage (not the parent directory for the .zip files). This way I got a list of the needed links, though not by being clever with the scraping as suggested in comments above. The following code got me where I wanted to be for now...

```
doc<-httr::GET("https://www.chesapeakeconservancy.org/conservation-innovation-center/high-resolution-data/land-cover-data-project/")

CIC<-"https://cicwebresources.blob.core.windows.net/chesapeakebaylandcover/MD/"
parsed<-XML::htmlParse(doc)
links <- XML::xpathSApply(parsed, "//a/@href")
todl<-links[grepl(CIC, links)]
```

The object `todl` (to download) had the links I was looking for, without knowing what layers were and were not included.