# grep on http using R

Tags: r

im unable to download the files, how can i update the functions, below, if i print some of the values file_names they are empty. what could be wrong?

```
# Set the download URL
url <- "https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/manuscript/xml/"

# Create a vector of file numbers to download
file_nums <- sprintf("%02d", 1:3) 

# Create a pattern to match the beginning of the file names
pattern <- paste0("^author_manuscript_xml.PMC0", file_nums)

# Get a vector of all file names from the URL and filter based on the pattern
file_names <- grep(pattern, list.files(url), value = TRUE)

# Loop through the file names and download each file
for (file_name in file_names) {
  file_url <- paste0(url, file_name)
  download.file(file_url, file_name)
}
```

Comment: `list.files` seems odd in the context of a http address, may give `character(0)` as response.

Comment: What does `list.files(url)` return? Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15954463/680068

Comment: character emtpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below solves the problem. The trick is to loop through the *pattern*, not the file names.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(rvest)
  library(dplyr)
})

# create a temp dir where to download the files
tmpdir <- tempdir()
tmpdir <- chartr("\\", "/", tmpdir)

# Create a vector of file numbers to download
file_nums <- sprintf("%02d", 1:3) 

# Create a pattern to match the beginning of the file names
pattern <- paste0("^author_manuscript_xml.PMC0", file_nums)

# this is the page link
link <- "https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/manuscript/xml/"

# read the page only once
page <- read_html(link)

# extract all links
file_names <- page %>%
  html_elements("a") %>%
  html_attr("href")

# this is probably necessary, some files are 1G+
old_opts <- options(timeout = max(600, getOption("timeout")))

# download the files
res <- lapply(pattern, \(p) {
  i <- grep(p, file_names)
  files <- file_names[i]
  urls <- paste0(link, files)
  destfls <- paste(tmpdir, files, sep = "/")
  mapply(\(u, d) {
    tryCatch(download.file(u, d), error = function(e) e)
  }, urls, destfls)
})

# restore the default timeout
options(old_opts)
```